# Status of ''self.head'' in a singly link list

Tags: python, data-structures

I've been practicing link list but can't understand what ''self.head'' actually refers.
Is it the first value in a list at index 0? And how can I print data inside the head?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def print_var(self):
        itr = self.head
        print(itr.data)
def insert_at_begining(self, data):
    node = Node(data, self.head)
    self.head = node
if __name__ = '__main__':
ll = Linkedlsit()
ll.insert_at_begining(3)
ll.insert_at_begining(4)
ll.insert_at_begining(6)
ll.insert_at_begining(8)
ll.print()
```

If I'm to call print fuction function, it will through an error.
(Say, linklist is not empty)

Comment: `self.head` refers to the first node of the linked list. In your example, you're trying to print an empty list (i.e., a list with no nodes). And since there is no error control in `point_var`, you get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.head` refers to the first `Node` in the list.  From there, you can "walk" the list with something like:

```py
current_node = ll.head
while current_node:
    print(f"Current node data: {current_node.data}")
    current_node = current_node.next

print("Reached End of List")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code and related comments

```
ll = LinkedList() # Create empty list
print(ll.head) # This prints None, because the list is empty, there are no nodes
ll.print_var() # This gives you an error. You're trying to print ll.head.data, but as shown before ll.head is None, not a Node
ll.head = Node('hello', ll.head) # The list now has one node
ll.print_var() # This is now working, and prints 'hello'
```